# NullPointerException on a listView.setAdapter() method

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-xml, android-dialogfragment

So i got this problem. and i know why. But first code so you will know why too :).

LoveMailsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.ex;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class LoveMailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
CustomDialogFragment CustomDialogFragment;

//CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView dialogListView;

TextView loveEmailOpeningWordsHeaderTextView;

String[] items = {"Hello","Hello there","Hi","Hi there"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_love_mails);

    viewsInitialization();

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    CustomDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();

    //customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(LoveMailsActivity.this, items);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoveMailsActivity.this, R.layout.list_view_row,R.id.row_text_view_id,items);
    dialogListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); // NullPointerExeption

    loveEmailOpeningWordsHeaderTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            CustomDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "Opening words");
        }
    });
} // End of onCreate() method

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.love_mails, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void viewsInitialization()
{
    loveEmailOpeningWordsHeaderTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.love_email_opening_words_header_text_view_id);
    dialogListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_id);
}

public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    TextView listViewItemTextView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ListView dialogListView;
    String[] items = {"Hello","Hello there","Hi","Hi there"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, container,false);

        getDialog().setTitle("Choose an option"); // Set dialog title

        listViewItemTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_item_text_view_id);
        dialogListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_list_view_id);

        getDialog().setTitle("Opening Words"); // Setting dialog title

        /*
        CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        dialogListView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
        */
        dialogListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), items[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

activity_love_mails.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.predesignedmails.LoveMailsActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_emai_to_send_to_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emai_to_send_to_text_view_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/love_email_email_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/emai_to_send_to_edit_text_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_emai_to_send_to_text_view_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_opening_words_header_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/love_email_opening_words_text_view_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_email_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/love_email_opening_words_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/love_email_opening_words_header_text_view_id"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i get the obvious `NullPointerException` on the `dialogListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); // NullPointerExeption` line because i dont have any `ListView` named `dialog_list_view_id` in the activity_love_mails.xml. I have that kind of `ListView` in another XML file:

dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/dialog_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now what am i doing wrong? My way of implementing this is obviously wrong and can't figure out what? The `CustomDialogFragment` class? the `ArrayAdapter`?

**EDIT**

LogCat:

```
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574): Process: com.example.predesignedmails, PID: 21574
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.predesignedmails/com.example.predesignedmails.LoveM    ailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual     method 'void  android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null  object reference
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2367)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:90    09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at com.example.predesignedmails.LoveMailsActivity.onCreate(LoveMailsActivity.java:45)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
09-02 19:47:08.208: E/AndroidRuntime(21574):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: I think they were wanting to get your logcat.

Comment: @codeMagic My ListView is in dialog.xml,

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado Added the LogCat.

Comment: Have you tried to actually import `dialog.xml` into your `activity_love_mails.xml` ?

Comment: @poss Never heard of that, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listview is in the dialog fragment and you are trying to call findViewById in the activity, hence it cannot be found and is therefore null.

Set your adapter to the listview within the dialog fragment in the onCreateView method.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks god almighty your a genius. Just a bummer people here don't appreciate other people efforts and down vote everything because they dont know how to solve it. Thanks mate and all who tried to help. Cheers!

Comment: @God did it really solved your problem , as I doubt that.

Comment: @PriyaSinghal It did. But if im mistaken(90% not) i will try your method. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Merely creating object of fragment doesn't mean it's onCreateView() or any other lifecycle method gets called.
Either you transact your fragment in the activity or declare your list view in the activity XML. 
Then only you can get listview.
For transacting fragment u search Google you will many examples.

Now in your case it's dialogfragment so this can be done using show().

Also when fragment is not kind of dialogfragment then findviewbyId () in the activity is valid as view of the fragment becomes part of the view hierarchy of the activity.